# "next element is already occupied" error

Tags: php, arrays

When we do something like:

```
<?php
$arr = array();
$arr[PHP_INT_MAX] = null;
$arr[] = null;
```

PHP gives the error message:

> **Warning**:  Cannot add element to the array as the next element is already occupied in **/home/yca/script.php** on line **4**

Why does the engine say that the next element is already occupied?

Is this a PHP bug?

Comment: Couldn't it be that the array gets filled up from 0 to MAX integer-value. And because it's max you can't add another element in the array?

Comment: Why are you even trying to use 2 billion elements?

Comment: It works [here](http://codepad.org/8fyIoxZ7). May be your PHP version is old.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld, that's not possible... it's a hashtable not an array. Only one entry is added.

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson, there's only 1 element.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar, I'm using version 5.3.26, 64 bit PHP.

Comment: @Pacerier Try same in 5.4.*

Comment: @Pacerier I mean, why does it matter?

Comment: @Pacerier - I don't understand. How is this a hashtable? For me it looks like an array? Ok, it's not filled up, but you're using the last possible element. And then you can't use the next one.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar could it be a 32 bit thing? This is using latest 5.5 (not sure what bit though) http://codepad.viper-7.com/WjsftE

Comment: @Mike may be, 32 bit means 32 bit OS version.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Yes, that's what I was talking about.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Actually, 32-bit means a word size of 32-bits. I can have a 64-bit processor running a 32-bit OS. With x86, I can have my processor run a 16-bit OS if I feel like it.

Answer (score 6):

This will literally answer all your questions about arrays in php

Mostly that they are not arrays. They are maps that look like arrays.

http://nikic.github.io/2012/03/28/Understanding-PHPs-internal-array-implementation.html

The following I pulled from the current 5.5.2 source:

The internal ulong nNextFreeElement will not increment any more thus giving this error

(the nNextFreeElement is now LONG_MAX which is already occupied)

From the PHP source:

```
if (zend_hash_next_index_insert(Z_ARRVAL_P(container), &new_zval, sizeof(zval *), (void **) &retval) == FAILURE) {
    zend_error(E_WARNING, "Cannot add element to the array as the next element is already occupied");
    retval = &EG(error_zval_ptr);
    Z_DELREF_P(new_zval);
}
```

Here is the portion of code that I believe is returning a failure in this case (since the index LONG_MAX is already occupied). In this call the flag = HASH_NEXT_INSERT.

```
if ((p->nKeyLength == 0) && (p->h == h)) {
    if (flag & HASH_NEXT_INSERT || flag & HASH_ADD) {
        return FAILURE;
    }
    ....
```

Comment: Could you find the commit message for that code? That'll explain the reasoning behind it.

Comment: @Daniel, isn't the error message bogus? Even if the next element is already occupied, we should have no errors. It should simply override.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php *"Note that when two identical index are defined, the last overwrite the first."*

Comment: I agree the error message is bogus. After looking at the code, the append will fail and in this case it will always have a wrong message.

Comment: @DanielWilliams, ok so you are saying besides the bogus error msg, this is defined behavior? There's no bugs with the logic of the code?

Comment: It is a bit late here. I think now that it is working correctly after tracing the code more. It looks like nNextFreeElement just doesn't increment so trying to append will try and put the new element in LONG_MAX which is already occupied.

Comment: @DanielWilliams, then it *is* a bug isn't it? Because putting the new element in LONG_MAX should work even if it is already occupied. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php  *"Note that when two identical index are defined, the last overwrite the first."*

Comment: The difference here is that this function is defined to only assign to the next available and unassigned numeric index. The unassigned requirement is not documented as far as I can tell but I think it makes logical sense. I would say the documentation should be updated for the "[]" operator (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)